# What would be the best way to generate proper words for my touch typing practice website?

Tags: javascript, text

I needed proper words for my touch typing website. Doesn't have to be a sentence but some actual words. Currently I'm just generating random gibberish which kind of works.

This function generates random text everytime the page is refreshed or the old set of words are completed.

```js
function generateText() {
  var easyText = ["a", "s", "d", "w", "r", "t", "h", "j", "n", "m", "i", "o", "v", "e", "f"];
  var hardText = ["g", "h", "z", "x", "c", "b", "k", "y", "q", "p", "u", "n", "m", "v", "l"];
  var string = "";
  count = 0;
  while (true) {
    if (easy) {
      string = createWords(easyText, string);
    } else {
      string = createWords(hardText, string);
    }
    if (count > 120) {
      break;
    }
  }
  displayText(string);
}

// This function is responsible for generating words. The words can be one to six letters long.
function createWords(array, string) {
  var wordLength = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 6);
  if (count > 0) {
    string = string + " ";
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < wordLength; i++) {
    var character = Math.floor(Math.random() * 15);
    string += array[character];
    count++;
  }
  return string;
}
```

Is there any API or some better way to do this?
Thank you

Comment: if your backend runs on linux (if you have a backend!) then there is a standard file "words" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Words_(Unix) which is a very convenient file if you just need some words. :p

Comment: "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"..[*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_quick_brown_fox_jumps_over_the_lazy_dog)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](https://gist.github.com/swenzel/70beac153cdf23803f89) is an amazing snippet at github from [@swenzel](https://gist.github.com/swenzel) that doesn't use hard-coded list of words but rather generates english sounding words on the fly using language statistics.

https://gist.github.com/swenzel/70beac153cdf23803f89

```js
 var grams = {
    " ": {0.6294: "s", 1.0: "t", 0.5166: "i", 0.2635: "c", 0.1255: "h", 0.7882: "a", 0.4297: "w", 0.1915: "b", 0.3464: "o", 0.0603: "f"},
    "a": {1.0: "n", 0.507: "l", 0.1379: "i", 0.3973: " ", 0.0446: "y", 0.6368: "r", 0.1865: "c", 0.0895: "m", 0.2906: "s", 0.7853: "t"},
    "c": {1.0: "o", 0.078: "r", 0.7882: "h", 0.3303: "t", 0.6334: "e", 0.181: "i", 0.0365: " ", 0.4808: "a", 0.2455: "k", 0.1214: "l"},
    "b": {1.0: "e", 0.0168: "s", 0.5666: "o", 0.3311: "l", 0.7064: "a", 0.042: " ", 0.2285: "i", 0.1634: "r", 0.1023: "y", 0.445: "u"},
    "e": {1.0: " ", 0.3763: "s", 0.2035: "a", 0.2859: "d", 0.0326: "c", 0.6218: "r", 0.1016: "e", 0.0666: "t", 0.14: "l", 0.4732: "n"},
    "d": {0.4397: "e", 1.0: " ", 0.0217: "d", 0.0671: "u", 0.044: "r", 0.0109: "y", 0.2946: "i", 0.0974: "s", 0.1495: "a", 0.2076: "o"},
    "g": {0.4683: "h", 1.0: " ", 0.0461: "s", 0.3648: "o", 0.0214: "n", 0.1991: "r", 0.2811: "a", 0.0805: "u", 0.1315: "i", 0.6221: "e"},
    "f": {0.1547: "a", 1.0: " ", 0.0923: "t", 0.0555: "u", 0.3867: "e", 0.2186: "f", 0.2981: "r", 0.0235: "l", 0.5046: "i", 0.7035: "o"},
    "i": {0.125: "e", 1.0: "n", 0.5324: "s", 0.1826: "d", 0.4017: "c", 0.3255: "o", 0.6677: "t", 0.2528: "l", 0.0382: "g", 0.081: "r"},
    "h": {0.0636: "t", 1.0: "e", 0.0099: "y", 0.3911: "i", 0.0382: "r", 0.0043: "n", 0.1563: "o", 0.2699: " ", 0.0219: "u", 0.5663: "a"},
    "k": {1.0: "e", 0.0184: "y", 0.2099: "s", 0.0336: "o", 0.1346: "n", 0.0828: "a", 0.664: " ", 0.0066: "u", 0.0526: "l", 0.3508: "i"},
    "j": {0.3455: "a", 1.0: "u", 0.0009: "s", 0.0314: " ", 0.2002: "e", 0.0618: "i", 0.0051: "p", 0.0021: "c", 0.6376: "o", 0.0132: "r"},
    "m": {1.0: "e", 0.7376: "a", 0.0544: "b", 0.2917: "i", 0.1154: "u", 0.4078: "o", 0.0265: "s", 0.1847: "p", 0.5582: " ", 0.0833: "m"},
    "l": {1.0: " ", 0.8256: "e", 0.0557: "s", 0.5064: "i", 0.2714: "o", 0.0221: "u", 0.1913: "y", 0.6551: "l", 0.3799: "a", 0.1173: "d"},
    "o": {0.4793: "u", 1.0: "n", 0.8009: " ", 0.0373: "o", 0.3502: "f", 0.1282: "w", 0.0817: "l", 0.1832: "t", 0.6375: "r", 0.2536: "m"},
    "n": {1.0: " ", 0.5597: "g", 0.4228: "t", 0.1167: "i", 0.3088: "e", 0.7117: "d", 0.2199: "s", 0.0764: "c", 0.0377: "a", 0.1673: "o"},
    "q": {1.0: "u", 0.0059: "l", 0.0136: "b", 0.0017: "s", 0.0348: "i", 0.0218: "a", 0.003: "w", 0.0043: "w", 0.0006: "v", 0.0888: " "},
    "p": {1.0: "e", 0.18: "i", 0.5315: "a", 0.4013: "l", 0.8133: "r", 0.124: "p", 0.2815: " ", 0.0687: "u", 0.6631: "o", 0.0274: "t"},
    "s": {1.0: " ", 0.2935: "i", 0.1824: "a", 0.3978: "e", 0.5411: "t", 0.0947: "s", 0.1379: "h", 0.053: "u", 0.0224: "p", 0.2328: "o"},
    "r": {1.0: "e", 0.1439: "t", 0.0554: "d", 0.2183: "s", 0.0245: "n", 0.5049: "o", 0.7461: " ", 0.0896: "y", 0.4002: "i", 0.3042: "a"},
    "u": {1.0: "r", 0.5156: "s", 0.2004: " ", 0.3647: "l", 0.259: "p", 0.1475: "c", 0.6674: "n", 0.0476: "e", 0.8267: "t", 0.0963: "g"},
    "t": {0.1525: "a", 0.0368: "u", 1.0: "h", 0.1056: "r", 0.4593: "o", 0.071: "s", 0.3457: "e", 0.7133: " ", 0.0183: "t", 0.243: "i"},
    "w": {0.0373: "s", 0.0059: "l", 0.8036: "a", 1.0: "i", 0.6122: "e", 0.3096: "o", 0.1913: " ", 0.0183: "r", 0.4543: "h", 0.0822: "n"},
    "v": {1.0: "e", 0.007: "s", 0.0014: "d", 0.0737: "o", 0.0234: " ", 0.0029: "r", 0.1484: "a", 0.0112: "y", 0.339: "i", 0.0045: "u"},
    "y": {0.204: "e", 1.0: " ", 0.0681: "i", 0.0136: "l", 0.0314: "t", 0.0223: "m", 0.303: "o", 0.0475: "a", 0.0056: "p", 0.1217: "s"},
    "x": {1.0: "p", 0.7464: " ", 0.0368: "u", 0.2706: "i", 0.1089: "c", 0.0215: "h", 0.01: "o", 0.5265: "t", 0.1895: "e", 0.3517: "i"},
    "z": {1.0: "e", 0.4678: " ", 0.2055: "o", 0.3289: "i", 0.0684: "y", 0.043: "u", 0.0075: "h", 0.024: "l", 0.6314: "a", 0.1182: "z"}
};
// create a sorted list for all keys
for(var key in grams){
    var sorted = [];
    for(var p in grams[key])
        sorted.push(p);
    grams[key].sorted = sorted.sort();
}

function generateWords(n){
    if(!n){
        n = 1;
    }
    var words = [];
    for(var i=0; i<n; i++){
        var w = ' ';
        // last will be our 1gram used to find a proper follower
        var last = w;
        while(true){

            var rand = Math.random();
            var p_list = grams[last].sorted;
            // find the follower corresponding to the random number
            // Note: p_list containes the accumulated probabilities of
            // the followers.
            for(var k=0; k+1 < p_list.length && p_list[k] < rand; k++);

            char = grams[last][p_list[k]];
            if(char === ' '){
                // space indicates end, but we do not want words shorter
                // than 5 so make sure we have minimum length
                if(w.length > 5)
                    break;
            }
            else{
                w += char;
            }
            last = char;
        }
        // strip the leading space before appending to the list
        words.push(w.substring(1));
    }
    return words;
}
 
$('#btn').click(function(){
  count = parseInt($('#txt').val())
  words = generateWords(count)
  $('#words').html( '<span>' + words.join('</span>, <span>') + '</span>')
});
```

```css
.words {
  background: yellow;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 500px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="txt" placeholder="generate how many words?">
<button id="btn">generate</button>

<div id="words"></div>
```